# Delphi Selection Sort seems to sort backwards

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

```
procedure TfrmSorting.btnSortClick(Sender: TObject);
var
K,L,I,iNumElements : integer;
sKeep : string;
begin
iNumElements := length(arrNames);
for K := 1 to iNumElements - 1 do
 begin
  for L := K + 1 to iNumElements do
    begin
      if arrNames[K] < arrNames[L] then
     begin
      sKeep := arrNames[L];
      arrNames[L] := arrNames[K];
      arrNames[K] := sKeep;
  end;
 end;
end;
reditNames.Lines.Clear;
I := 1;
for K := 1 to iNumElements - 1 do
  begin
    reditNames.Lines.Add(arrNames[I]);
    I := I + 1;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using this sorting algorithm to sort an Array. I then diplay the contents on a richedit but instead of going from A..Z its displays Z..A. Is there a problem with the algorithm or the way im adding lines to the richedit? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K is less than L and you swap items if the K-th is less than the L-th. You have your comparison the wrong way round. Use `>` rather than `<`.

Your indexing is dubious also. Is your array really 1-based? And why do you only add 1 to N-1 to the output? Are you missing the last item In other words, I suspect there are other defects in your code. You have not shown it all so I cannot be sure.

Finally, why not use the built in sorting functionality?

Comment: @RT5754 If you're learning, you need to also learn debugging techniques. 1) Learn to step through your algorithm on paper. Draw what a small array looks like and track each variable at each step of your code. 2) Learn to use the debugger. When you step through the code 1 line at a time, you'd see exactly how the array is changing and would have figured out for yourself why your code sorted descending.

Comment: Finally, general tip: No matter sorting algorithm you use, you can always reverse the direction of the sort by reversing the comparison.